# Extract row with maximum value from multiply represented second variable

Tags: text-processing, r

I have a problem that I cant seem to solve.

I have a massive tab-delimited text file similar to:

```
chr 10 20 20 a
chr 30 40 10 b
chr 30 40 15 b
chr 30 40 11 b
```

What I need is to: 
1) extract all unique rows 
2) Where column 5 is represented multiple times (eg b), the row with the maximum value in column 4.

So the rows I need in the above example are:

```
chr 10 20 20 a (this is a unique row)
chr 30 40 15 b (this is the row with maximum value in column 4 when column 5 is represented multiple times.
```

Is there is a simple way to do this?

Comment: actually, all the input rows in their whole representation are unique. So, elaborate your uniqueness.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, well, they did mention having multiples of the value in column 5, so we might at least consider asking if that was the intended meaning?

Comment: Why do you want the "a" row when it only appears once? This seems to contradict your 2nd criterion.

Comment: @glennjackman Its information that I need (unique lines). I will remove all unique lines first and then print out the max of the multiple represented group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, group the lines by the fifth column, and for each group, print the line where the fourth column is greatest?

Assuming you have no negative numbers:

```
$ awk '$4 > val[$5] {val[$5] = $4; line[$5] = $0} 
       END {for (x in line) print line[x] }' < foo.txt
chr 10 20 20 a       
chr 30 40 15 b
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!!!!! Awesome, thank you soooo much :)

Answer (score 0):

example.txt

```
chr 10 20 20 a
chr 30 40 10 b
chr 30 40 15 b
chr 30 40 11 b
```

code

```
 awk '$5== "a" {print $0}' l.txt | sort -k4 -nr | sed -n '1p' ; awk '$5=="b" {print $0}' l.txt | sort -k4  -nr | sed -n '1p'
```

Output

```
chr 10 20 20 a
chr 30 40 15 b
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {count[$5]++; if ($4 > max[$5]) max[$5] = $4; next} 
    count[$5] > 1 && $4 == max[$5] && !seen[$0]++
' file file
```

```
chr 30 40 15 b
```

Process the file twice:

- the first time, count how often the 5th field occurs, and find the maximum 4th field for each 5th field value
- the second time, process your criteria:

  - only records where the 5th field appears more than once, and
  - only records with max 4th field, and
  - only unique records

---

If you want to see lines where the count is one, then we can simply write

```
awk 'NR == FNR {if ($4 > max[$5]) max[$5]=$4; next} $4==max[$5] && !seen[$0]++' file file
```

```
chr 10 20 20 a
chr 30 40 15 b
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet:

```
# Utility functions: print-as-echo, print-line-with-visual-space.
pe() { for _i;do printf "%s" "$_i";done; printf "\n"; }
pl() { pe;pe "-----" ;pe "$*"; }
pl " Input data file $FILE:"
head $FILE

pl " Expected output:"
cat $E

pl " Results:"
datamash -t" " --group=5 max 4 --full <$FILE |
cut -d" " -f1-5
```

produces:

```
-----
 Input data file data1:
chr 10 20 20 a
chr 30 40 10 b
chr 30 40 15 b
chr 30 40 11 b

-----
 Expected output:
chr 10 20 20 a       
chr 30 40 15 b

-----
 Results:
chr 10 20 20 a
chr 30 40 15 b
```

For a system like:

```
OS, ker|rel, machine: Linux, 3.16.0-4-amd64, x86_64
Distribution        : Debian 8.9 (jessie) 
bash GNU bash 4.3.30
datamash (GNU datamash) 1.2
cut (GNU coreutils) 8.23
```

Some details for datamash:

```
datamash        command-line calculations (man)
Path    : /usr/local/bin/datamash
Version : 1.2
Type    : ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYS ...)
Help    : probably available with -h,--help
Home    : https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/ (pm)
Home    : http://www.gnu.org/software/datamash (doc)
```